# sourceMap set to true everywhere, but no typescript sources appearing under my Firefox browser debugger (Angular 14)

Tags: angular, typescript, debugging, source-maps

source maps are expected to come quite instantaneously on web browsers, when starting an Angular application in dev mode, with `ng serve`. Provided `"sourceMap": true` is sat, according to what I read over the Internet.

This doesn't appear to cause troubles to most developpers.
But, I'm not among the lucky ones, and my Firefox browser doesn't show the typescript counterparts of the javascript that Angular produced.

I'm using Angular 14.

[image]

Did I missed to parameterize somewhere, something?

Most of what is below was written by angular plugins. But maybe something is inaccurate or lacking.

Can you help me?

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2020",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

**angular.json**

```json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "etude": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/etude",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/ol/ol.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "etude:build"
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "etude:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "etude:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "etude:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "etude",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "buildProduction": "ng build --configuration production",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "openapi": "openapi-generator generate -g typescript-angular -i ../../../../metier-et-gestion/dev/GenerationOpenAPI/openapi/openapi.json -o ./openapi --skip-validate-spec"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.2.12",
    "@angular/common": "^14.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.2.12",
    "@angular/core": "^14.2.12",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.2.12",
    "@angular/router": "^14.2.12",
    "@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli": "^1.0.13-4.3.1",
    "ol": "^7.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.4.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.10",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.2.12",
    "@angular/language-service": "^14.2.12",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.1",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~10.9.1",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.6.4",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "codelyzer": {
      "@angular/core": ">=14.0.0",
      "@angular/compiler": ">=14.0.0"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well angular uses webpack to build or serve. So you should look in the source navigation tab for webpack and inside webpack you should find your .ts files. Hotkey user in Chrome could press CTRL + P and type in the name of your file and the browser will search for it.

Comment: @MehyarSawas If I understand you well, I have something to install on my Firefox side in order to make webpack start working and show the typescript sources that my Angular `ng serve` command is "one way or another" already emitting/linking?

Comment: No, it is already there in the browser but not und the root path of your project, instead it is under the webpack source

Comment: @MehyarSawas I don't see clearly what I should do to finish. Could you write an answer to show me my missing steps clearer? It would be nice from you, and I would appreciate it greatly!

Comment: Before I write my answer, do you see "webpack://" under sources on the left sidebar in your developer tool?  Or share a screenshot of the whole area.

Comment: If you do not see "webpack://" I see in your angular.json also you have under "serve" the config "configuration" "production". I am not sure if this is a correct, but this could be the problem. If you try the remove the whole "configuration" part under serve and try again

Comment: I've updated the post to reflect the change you suggested me, and put a bigger image showing that `webpack;//` isn't here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've succeeded in my researches, glad to your help.

[image]

*Angular 14* isn't working the same manner than previous versions.
Two changes have to be done, both in `angular.json` file:

Comparing to my opening post, to resolve my issue, I had to:

1. On architect, build section, add a development configuration:

```json
"architect": {
  "build": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
    "options": {
      "outputPath": "dist/etude",
      "index": "src/index.html",
      "main": "src/main.ts",
      "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
      "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "aot": true,
      "assets": [
        "src/favicon.ico",
        "src/assets"
      ],
      "styles": [
        "node_modules/ol/ol.css",
        "src/styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": []
    },
    "configurations": {
      "production": {
        "fileReplacements": [
          {
            "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
            "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
          }
        ],
        "optimization": true,
        "outputHashing": "all",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "namedChunks": true,
        "extractLicenses": true,
        "vendorChunk": false,
        "buildOptimizer": true,
        "budgets": [
          {
            "type": "initial",
            "maximumWarning": "2mb",
            "maximumError": "5mb"
          },
          {
            "type": "anyComponentStyle",
            "maximumWarning": "6kb",
            "maximumError": "10kb"
          }
        ]
      },

      "development": {
        "buildOptimizer": false,
        "optimization": false,
        "vendorChunk": true,
        "extractLicenses": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "namedChunks": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

2. On its `serve` part, do this change:

```json
"serve": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
  "options": {
    "browserTarget": "etude:build"
  },

  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      "browserTarget": "etude:build:production"
    },

    "development": {
      "browserTarget": "etude:build:development"
    }
  },

  "defaultConfiguration": "development"
}
```

And then, a classical `ng serve` shows the typescript files, eventually.